# Removing the Apple sound effect when changing volume levels in a boot camp assisted installation of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot-camp, osx-mavericks, system-sounds

I find the sound effect that plays when you adjust the volume levels on a mac very annoying.  The issue is I can't find a way to remove this on the windows side of my mac.  I'm fairly certain I managed to do this in an older version of boot camp and windows by just adjusting some settings in the control panel.  I believe I've exhausted all the obvious and googled solutions so I'm turning to this great community for help.  Using a mid 2012 15 inch retina macbook with a windows 8 operating system and Mavericks running on the other side.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this problem myself... and yes, greetings in questions are discouraged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @andyras Can you check if the recently posted answer is valid?

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on the speaker icon in the taskbar notification area (bottom right). Click "Open Volume Mixer". Scroll to the right until you see Bootcamp. Click the speaker icon below the slider for Bootcamp to mute it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click Volume icon in Windows system tray
2. Click "Open Volume Mixer" from context menu
3. If item "Boot Camp Manager"

   - **IS** showing:

     - click on Blue Speaker below slider to mute channel
     - Alternatively you can pull slider all the way down, but this may try setting a ratio for volume control in the future
   - is **NOT** showing:

     - Hit a volume change key so the beep plays. This will cause the "Boot Camp Manager" section to now show in the Volume Mixer window. Now use bullet point tips above for **IS** showing

*Reason for adding this to older post: This is what came up when I was searching for an answer to this same issue, however, the previous lone (an unvoted for) answer left me confused when the "Boot Camp Manager" item was missing from the list. I figured this out on my own and felt that it should be added for the next person looking for more information on this.*

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I don't have Boot Camp installed anymore. Maybe someone else can verify this? @andryas?